# Can an Airflow DAG schedule be altered in The Airflow UI?

Tags: airflow

I'm new to Apache Airflow.  I have been modifying the schedule_interval and replacing the python script, each time I want to change the execution time.

Can I change the DAG schedule without uploading a new python script?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

There is an Airflow Plugin which allows for (visual) Dag-Generation and Modification, see [here](https://github.com/airflow-plugins/airflow-dag-creation-manager-plugin). It seems to be outdated and not very actively developed, though.

The general idea for Airflow is, roughly speaking, etl-as-code, including benefits like code versioning etc., i.e. you need to be aware of problems arising from redefining such central aspects as the schedule time from the UI. F.e., when you could edit the schedule-time in the UI (but that would not alter the code itself), what would be the state of your DAG? However, it`s for sure not impossible and Airflow's design allows for such modifications.

**tldr;** One could of course customize the UI (see above, f.e. using Airflow Plugins) and in fact your requirement is very understandable, especially to account for non-technical users which can't upload/modify code.

Another, probably easier option might be to use [Variables](https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html) in Airflow, i.e. pull the schedule-time/cron-linke schedule-string (`1 * * * *`,`daily` etc.) from the an Airflow Variable; such Variables can be altered in the GUI, so this might work out for you.

Comment: The Variables option is a great idea!

Answer (score 0):

The Variable option doesn't work, at least in Airflow 2.0.1
The message :

> Broken DAG: [/opt/airflow/dags/ADB-365/big-kahuna-365-adb-incremental.py] Invalid Cron expression: Exactly 5 or 6 columns has to be specified for iteratorexpression.

appears in the main view.